# Extracting data from text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I extract text data from a text file using javascript? I am making an online dictionary. I can code HTML and CSS well but not javascript.

Word Will be entered in first textbox then search button will be clicked and results will be shown in bottom textbox.
The data in text file is like "apple|a juicy fruit"
                              (without the quotations"
Now I want the text in search field to check up words before "|" sign and if match is found word/words after "|" will be sent to result field.
How can I do this using javascript?

My HTML code for the project is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Online Dictionary</title>
    <style>
      .field{
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      #result_field{
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 247px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your word here..." name="search_field" id="search_field" class="field">

    <input type="button" value="SEARCH" name="btn" id="btn" class="btn"> <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Meaning here..." name="result_field" id="result_field" class="field">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will have to use PHP

Comment: you want to read a local text file?

Comment: clarification required.. are you going to search in a file which is at client side or in the file is at server side?

Comment: It depends on the rest of your stack.. Are you using MEAN or ... ?
This might help you : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: The text file will be at the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Ajax.

Ajax is what do a request to a file from a server, so with it you can:

- Check velocity of user network;
- Get content of file.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

I made few simple functions, you can check them [here.](http://pastebin.com/r80RjFz9)

To use one of the functions above you can add lines like these:

```
$GET('file.txt?c=0',function(result){/* Success function */},function(e){/* Error function */});

$GET('dictionary.txt?anyvalue=0',function(text){alert(text);},function(e){/* Error function */});

/* in ahead of the link you will have to include the ?urlvar=value to the function works, */
/*     I still didn't leave the function complete */
```

**Note:** case you want to request a file from another server then the file has to allow servers to access it (to allow or not allow you can use PHP or htaccess).

As @Stephan Bijzitter said, you can use PHP (or ASP) - there you can result the right meaning of a word easily.

A example is:

```
if($_GET['word']=="PC"){echo "Meaning";}
switch($_GET['word']){case "Word":echo "A word?";break;}
/* In PHP, $_GET['word'] returns the value of a parameter in page URL called "word" */
```

Comment: I think I can use these bits to make my dictionary.

Comment: Someone else also recommended me Ajax.